# Getting/Setting Terminal Keycode in Win32 gVim

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, microsoft-windows

I wanted a binding for `<C-;>` to `<End>`, but it looks like that key either doesn't exist or does, but falls outside of the range of keycodes that Vim handles internally, or something.

So, on my personal Linux system, I use Alacritty, and just have a binding in it's settings to map Control+Semicolon to `\x1b[F`, job done.

Now I have a Windows system for work, and on it I'm running gVim with my same vimrc, and that "binding" obviously doesn't work because it's at the terminal level. Is there any way in Win32 gVim to remap an input keycode to a literal escape, like I've done above?

Thanks!

EDIT: It hadn't occurred to me until just now to check if Alacritty might have a Windows release, which it does, which solves my particular problem. I'll leave this unanswered though, if someone actually does know of a way to do this, for future reference.

Comment: `<c-;>` is not universally mapable. See https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4 and https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. This question is asking whether there is a method of rebinding inputs to gVim, as one might do on a terminal, not mapping the key within vim. I don't know what underlies gVim, and I was operating under the assumption it might be some kind of terminal emulation that could be configured.

Comment: In Alacritty, I've bound <End> to the motion in question, because I want both keys to do it, then in the terminal configuration I have Control+Semicolon set to produce End, so it all works out

Comment: as mentioned, that is not possible. gvim has totally different from a terminal emulator

Comment: That was not mentioned. Only that `<C-;>` is not mappable, a fact which I already knew, and said as such. I know that gVim is not a terminal, but I don't know how, which is precisely why I'd asked this question, to determine whether it was possible to do the sorts of things in gVim that one would in a terminal emulator.